# Find guids between strings

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

### Problem:

Trying to get all matches where guid = guid. I'm expecting to receive a collection of matches where one match looks like:

```
{9659BAE5-632F-4195-BD5D-414C1F2C1066} = {6E298F2A-129A-4491-B053-F12D67561572}
```

I'm trying to match all of the guid = guid between `GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution` and `EndGlobalSection` specifically. There are other places in the file where guid = guid exists.

Here is a data snippet:

```
    Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Client", "Applications\", "{297BE1A3-A6A3-4835-BB87-63B4B4E2AE0D}"
        ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
            {A459406A-94FF-4CA9-8183-C7472419CC7D} = {A459406A-94FF-4CA9-8183-C7472419CC7D}
        EndProjectSection
    EndProject

    GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution
        {3D84A2B1-536D-4953-B331-D86E421905E7} = {AF46FD2E-710D-49CD-A203-CB0F8B7EF415}
        {02CB05EC-6902-417E-AD50-B3910B245B22} = {2F54A6F1-5D32-4673-8AEE-B845CC622D64}
        {DE303EF0-E3B1-4BA9-8CB3-544D37D29576} = {2F54A6F1-5D32-4673-8AEE-B845CC622D64}
        {5A095236-0EE1-4480-B7A6-833ECCFE4257} = {AF070137-227F-42F7-9487-00CB26C46E04}
        {6CCA189C-0D45-4E80-8486-38AB3E625E69} = {AF070137-227F-42F7-9487-00CB26C46E04}
        {EAE3152A-C003-4E39-BFB7-B4F7CACE1606} = {AF070137-227F-42F7-9487-00CB26C46E04}
        {9659BAE5-632F-4195-BD5D-414C1F2C1066} = {6E298F2A-129A-4491-B053-F12D67561572}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

### What I've Tried:

Here's what I'm using to match guid = guid

```
{[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}} = {[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}}
```

This works fine except it doesn't discriminate against the location of the match, obviously. So I receive other matches from other parts of the file.
I've been trying to use a positive look behind like so (with many variations):

```
(?<=GlobalSection\(NestedProjects\) = preSolution(\r\n|.)+?)
```

Am I misusing the lookbehind or something else?

Comment: What language are you using here?

Comment: @danseery I didn't post any code because my thinking is this "should" be language agnostic. However, its being used in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following regex and got correct results using your example.

```
(?<= GlobalSection\(NestedProjects\) = preSolution(\r\n|.)+?){[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}} = {[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}}
```

You may need to use RegexOptions.Multiline as an option in your regex since it is C# (if you're not already).

**EDIT**

I wrote a little test program with your data snippet.  I doubled it to make sure it did not just match the first group after `GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution`
`matches` only returned the GUIDs between `GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution` and `EndGlobalSection` for both sections.

The line `{A459406A-94FF-4CA9-8183-C7472419CC7D} = {A459406A-94FF-4CA9-8183-C7472419CC7D}` was not in the matched results as I would expect.  I hope something in this code helps you out.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\test\directory\test.txt");

        string pattern =
            @"(?<=GlobalSection\(NestedProjects\) = preSolution(\r\n|.)+?){[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}} = {[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}}";
        Regex re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);


        MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(input);

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.Write(match);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Looks like the only difference is the additional space before the `GlobalSec...`. Thanks, though.